# When I try to create two slider boxes on the same page, it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_comparison.asp)

I tried creating table and copying the html over and it didn't work. I'm trying to create some before and afters.  I'm not 100% on Javascript, but I'm thinking there is something in there preventing it.

Sorry I have to link to the code.  It would not let me post with so much copypasta'd code.

Comment: Your link brings to a w3School article

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, you will need to be a bit clearer as to what you are trying to do, and what isn't working for you. How are you trying to create 2 slider boxes? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can use something like: https://codepen.io/pen/ to give an full example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of sliders working using the same HTML except for the images. Added table and removed CSS that was sizing the images.

```js
function initComparisons() {
  var x, i;
  /*find all elements with an "overlay" class:*/
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("img-comp-overlay");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    /*once for each "overlay" element:
    pass the "overlay" element as a parameter when executing the compareImages function:*/
    compareImages(x[i]);
  }

  function compareImages(img) {
    var slider, img, clicked = 0,
      w, h;
    /*get the width and height of the img element*/
    w = img.offsetWidth;
    h = img.offsetHeight;
    /*set the width of the img element to 50%:*/
    img.style.width = (w / 2) + "px";
    /*create slider:*/
    slider = document.createElement("DIV");
    slider.setAttribute("class", "img-comp-slider");
    /*insert slider*/
    img.parentElement.insertBefore(slider, img);
    /*position the slider in the middle:*/
    slider.style.top = (h / 2) - (slider.offsetHeight / 2) + "px";
    slider.style.left = (w / 2) - (slider.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
    /*execute a function when the mouse button is pressed:*/
    slider.addEventListener("mousedown", slideReady);
    /*and another function when the mouse button is released:*/
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", slideFinish);
    /*or touched (for touch screens:*/
    slider.addEventListener("touchstart", slideReady);
    /*and released (for touch screens:*/
    window.addEventListener("touchstop", slideFinish);

    function slideReady(e) {
      /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
      e.preventDefault();
      /*the slider is now clicked and ready to move:*/
      clicked = 1;
      /*execute a function when the slider is moved:*/
      window.addEventListener("mousemove", slideMove);
      window.addEventListener("touchmove", slideMove);
    }

    function slideFinish() {
      /*the slider is no longer clicked:*/
      clicked = 0;
    }

    function slideMove(e) {
      var pos;
      /*if the slider is no longer clicked, exit this function:*/
      if (clicked == 0) return false;
      /*get the cursor's x position:*/
      pos = getCursorPos(e)
      /*prevent the slider from being positioned outside the image:*/
      if (pos < 0) pos = 0;
      if (pos > w) pos = w;
      /*execute a function that will resize the overlay image according to the cursor:*/
      slide(pos);
    }

    function getCursorPos(e) {
      var a, x = 0;
      e = e || window.event;
      /*get the x positions of the image:*/
      a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
      /*calculate the cursor's x coordinate, relative to the image:*/
      x = e.pageX - a.left;
      /*consider any page scrolling:*/
      x = x - window.pageXOffset;
      return x;
    }

    function slide(x) {
      /*resize the image:*/
      img.style.width = x + "px";
      /*position the slider:*/
      slider.style.left = img.offsetWidth - (slider.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
    }
  }
}

/*Execute a function that will execute an image compare function for each element with the img-comp-overlay class:*/
initComparisons();
```

```css
div[class^="img-comp-container"] {
  position: relative;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.img-comp-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-comp-img img {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.img-comp-slider {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  /*set the appearance of the slider:*/
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  opacity: 0.7;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table class="cool" cellpadding="10">
  <tr>
    <td width="500">
      <div class="img-comp-container1">
        <div class="img-comp-img">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/400" width="500" height="400">
        </div>
        <div class="img-comp-img img-comp-overlay">
          <img src="http://placebear.com/500/400" width="500" height="400">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="img-comp-container2">
        <div class="img-comp-img">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300" width="500" height="300">
        </div>
        <div class="img-comp-img img-comp-overlay">
          <img src="http://baconmockup.com/500/300/" width="500" height="300">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm completely new to this site, so forgive me if I'm not responding correctly.  This did work. I'm trying to stack them side by side.  I'm trying to use a table to get it to work, but the sliders then overlay the table and each other.  If I change the size of the pictures in the html, it overlays.  It seems like there is positioning code I am not seeing.  Do I need to do inline block in the CSS?  Then I still have the issue of resizing.

Comment: You'll have to share your code to easily identify where the issue is. Can you please edit your question by using a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=zhQA7mL6vF  I added table code to the html.  Also, if I resize the width and height in the html it breaks

Comment: I updated my example, both slides are next to each other and the images are different sizes

Comment: sorry it took so long to get back...If I change the first slider images sizes to 500x400 it runs under the second slider image.  Is there a way to some how put them into a cellpadded table so the table properties dictate position?

Comment: I added a table with cellpadding and removed the image widths being defined by css.  The only width being applied is now on the first table column. If this helps, please mark this as the correct answer. 